# data inserted was not reflected into join table by using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

In Film.java

```
package com.flp.ems.domain;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Film
{
@Id private int film_id;
private String title;
private String description;
private Date release_year;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="language_id")
private Language language;

private float rental_duration;
private float rental_rate;
private int length;
private int replacement_cost;
private String rating;
private String special_features;
private Date last_update;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "film_actor", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "film_id", referencedColumnName = "film_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id", referencedColumnName = "actor_id"))
private Set<Actor> actor;

@ManyToOne
private Category category;

public Film()
{

}

public int getFilm_id() {
    return film_id;
}

public void setFilm_id(int film_id) {
    this.film_id = film_id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Date getRelease_year() {
    return release_year;
}

public void setRelease_year(Date release_year) {
    this.release_year = release_year;
}

public Language getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setLanguage(Language language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public float getRental_duration() {
    return rental_duration;
}

public void setRental_duration(float rental_duration) {
    this.rental_duration = rental_duration;
}

public float getRental_rate() {
    return rental_rate;
}

public void setRental_rate(float rental_rate) {
    this.rental_rate = rental_rate;
}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setLength(int length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public int getReplacement_cost() {
    return replacement_cost;
}

public void setReplacement_cost(int replacement_cost) {
    this.replacement_cost = replacement_cost;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public String getSpecial_features() {
    return special_features;
}

public void setSpecial_features(String special_features) {
    this.special_features = special_features;
}

public Date getLast_update() {
    return last_update;
}

public void setLast_update(Date last_update) {
    this.last_update = last_update;
}

public Set<Actor> getActor() {
    return actor;
}

public void setActor(Set<Actor> actor) {
    this.actor = actor;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Film [film_id=" + film_id + ", title=" + title + ", description=" + description + ", release_year="
            + release_year + ", language=" + language + ", rental_duration=" + rental_duration + ", rental_rate="
            + rental_rate + ", length=" + length + ", replacement_cost=" + replacement_cost + ", rating=" + rating
            + ", special_features=" + special_features + ", last_update=" + last_update + ", actor=" + actor
            + ", category=" + category + "]";
}
}
```

in Actor.java
    package com.flp.ems.domain;

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Actor 
{
@Id private int actor_id;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
private Date last_update;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="actor")
private Set<Film> films;

public Actor()
{

}

public int getActor_id() {
    return actor_id;
}

public void setActor_id(int actor_id) {
    this.actor_id = actor_id;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public Date getLast_update() {
    return last_update;
}

public void setLast_update(Date date) {
    this.last_update = date;
}

public Set<Film> getFilms() {
    return films;
}

public void setFilms(Set<Film> films) {
    this.films = films;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Actor [actor_id=" + actor_id + ", first_name=" + first_name + ", last_name=" + last_name
            + ", last_update=" + last_update + ", films=" + films + "]";
}   
}
```

it should join the film table and the actor table and it should create a film_actor table.

my issue is when i am inserting the data into the film table and the actor table the data was not automatically inserted into film_actor table why?

Comment: you received an error? Or what exactly happened?

Comment: no error,but when i do persist the data was getting inserted to film table and the actor table but the film_actor table was kept empty @Patrick

Comment: Refer this link http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: i tried it before but it did not work

Comment: Hi @RaghuRamMullapudi, Can you please post your `Main class`, also Your web.xml please

Comment: @Rakesh do you mean that pom.xml or persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding you need to create model for "film_actor" ,The Following link help you. check this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/